# undefined method in object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I get an error when I want to compile the following code...

I get undefined method when I'm trying to set a variable with the Filters class..

```
trace(filters.txt()); // returns undefined method

trace(filters); // returns [object Filters]
```

but I'm using this same object in other scripts without problems?

```
package player {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import filters.Filters;

    public class Time_bar extends Sprite {
        private var bar = null;

        public var color = null;
        public var _w = 0;
        public var _h = 0;
        public var _x = 0;
        public var _y = 0;

        public function Time_bar(){
            this.bar = new Sprite();
            addChild(this.bar);
        }

        public function cnstr(){
            this.bar.graphics.beginFill('0x'+this.color);
            this.bar.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, this._w, this._h);
            this.bar.graphics.endFill();
            this.bar.x = this._x;
            this.bar.y = this._y;
            this.bar.alpha = 0.75;
            this.bar.scaleX = 0;

            var filters = new Filters();
            trace(filters);
            trace(filters.txt());
            //filters.txt(this.bar);
        }

        public function progress(float){
            this.bar.scaleX = float;
        }
    }
}
```

the Filters class looks like this:

```
package filters {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import filters.Filters_glow;

    public class Filters extends Sprite {
        private var Glow = new Filters_glow();

        public function txt(instance){
            Glow.color = '93fafe';

            instance.filters = [Glow.filter()];
        }

        public function loader(instance){
            Glow.color = '93fafe';
            Glow.alpha = 0.5;

            instance.filters = [Glow.filter()];
        }
    }
}
```

Filter_glow:

```
package filters {
    import flash.filters.GlowFilter;

    public class Filters_glow {
        public var color = '000000';
        public var alpha = 0.25; // range: 0-1
        public var blurX = 4; // range: 0-255; optimized values: 2,4,8,16 etc
        public var blurY = 4; // range: 0-255; optimized values: 2,4,8,16 etc
        public var strength = 1; // range: 0-255
        public var quality = 3; // range: 0-15
        public var inner = false;
        public var knockout = false;

        public function filter(){
            this.color = '0x'+this.color;

            return new GlowFilter(this.color, this.alpha, this.blurX, this.blurY, this.strength, this.quality, this.inner, this.knockout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `filters.txt(this.bar)` return? My logic says that you should get an `incorrect number of arguments Error` instead of the one you're getting.

Comment: look in the 2nd part og the script.. it sets the filters property on an instance

Comment: it returns noting.. void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _filters = new Filters();
_filters.txt(this.bar);
```

aparently filters is a reserved property name.. after changing filters to _filters the error disapeared :)

Answer (score 0):

To verify whether the method "txt" exists on the filters object you'd have to write `trace(filters.txt);`. Instead you're executing the txt-method with a missing parameter by adding the brackets. And while executing, it tries to access `instance` which is undefined. I agree with Matti though that the error message should say something else.

As to why `filters.txt(this.bar);` doesn't work, I suspect the problem lies elsewhere, can you include the invoking code and the Filters_glow class?

Comment: I have now added Filters_glow to the text :)

Comment: Have you tried exchanging the line "trace(filters.txt());" with "trace(filters.txt);"? that should already get rid of one error.

Comment: I solved it... hehe.. its because I use the variable "filters" which aparently is a reserved property name.. after I changed it the error disapeared :) but thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly visible. You are not passing the only required argument to the function txt.

```
public function txt(instance){
            Glow.color = '93fafe';

            instance.filters = [Glow.filter()];
        }
```

So you can only call txt function by passing it an instance even. something like:

```
trace(filters.txt(YourObject));
```

I assume the argument is an instance of the object you want to apply the filter to or something like that. Well it's your function...

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your code as follows, this might help with the error:

```
 //...
public class Filters extends Sprite {
private var Glow: Filters_glow;
    public function Filters(){
        Glow = new Filters_glow();
    }
    public function txt(instance: DisplayObject = null): Boolean{
        if(!instance){
            return false;
        }
        Glow.color = '93fafe';

        instance.filters = [Glow.filter()];
        return true;
    }
//...
```

Comment: Is really adding a condition to the function required? OP is only using it for debugging purpose. Also getting a boolean false is not perhaps what the OP is trying to achieve using the trace statement.

Comment: @ loxxy - yes, it doesn't make much sense, but it seems reasonable to me to start with getting rid of an error

Comment: Time_bar.as, Line 30 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method txt.
I added "=null" in the functions arguments and added if(!instance) reutrn false to the function, but still the same error

Comment: @ user555222 - is your `txt` function equal to mine?

Comment: I solved it... hehe.. its because I use the variable "filters" which aparently is a reserved property name.. after I changed it the error disapeared :) but thanks for your time